# DNSoverTLS for upstream recursion requests in Bind9/Stunnel

Tags: dns, tls, bind, recursive

There is a lot of information out there about DNSoverTLS and different combinations of setups, and I've slowly been going through different combinations to get the right setup for us, but it's led to a few questions I need help clarifying.

After starting with `dnsmasq` and then `systemd-resolved` we quickly(*read:after lots of work*) realized that in our setup we needed a DNS system that supported *Recursion* which is out of the scope of these two.  The very specific reason we need recursion is due to public resolvers not resolving requests for Anti-Spam/RBL services like Spamhaus, so we need to be able to speak directly to root servers (*this is how I understand it anyway*). So I'm settling into `bind`.

I understand that Bind9 does not support `DNSoverTLS` itself, and so uses `Stunnel` to encrypt it's communications, but the path from there is where I get a little confused...

1. Is Stunnel encrypting it's downstream (client requests), or upstream (recursion/resolver) requests, or both?
2. Am I correct in my understanding that recursion means that the request goes directly to a root DNS server, then recursively iterates down until it finds the authoritative nameserver and can resolve the request, rather than going to a resolver like Quad9/Cloudflare/Google/etc.?
3. Do the root DNS servers support DNSoverTLS themselves or only said resolver services?

Ours is a *standalone* server, it's not meant to be an open resolver for anything other than internal requests from applications such as `postfix`, or clients connected via VPN directly to the server, nor is it authoritative, it is only a caching DNS server.

My goal is to encrypt our upstream/recursive requests, am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is stunnel encrypting it's downstream (client requests), or upstream (recursion/resolver) requests, or both?

Assuming you are following [this ISC BIND guide](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01386), then stunnel is decrypting incoming DoT connections while BIND is not making any recursive requests for stunnel to encrypt.

- stunnel listens on port 853 for incoming DoT connections, then passes any DNS requests to BIND on port 53 (the standard port for unencrypted DNS).
- Forwarded outgoing requests from BIND are passed to stunnel on port 1053, then stunnel sends the final DoT connection out on port 853.
- The normal fallback to standard resolution is disabled with the `forward only;` directive.

> Am I correct in my understanding that recursion means that the request goes directly to a root DNS server, then recursively iterates down until it finds the authoritative nameserver and can resolve the request, rather than going to a resolver like Quad9/Cloudflare/Google/etc.?

"Recursion" means that the server attempts to track down the IP of any unknown domains itself (rather than relying on other DNS servers to do this on its behalf). But what you describe is the typical process, yes.

> Do the root DNS servers support DNSoverTLS themselves or only said resolver services?

While I could be mistaken, my understanding is that the root name servers do not support DoT (so only DNS servers that are configured to handle it, like the ones you describe).

Comment: So it sounds like, if I'm not intending on serving clients outside of the two I described (local daemons, and VPN clients), then there's no need/point of Stunnel as I won't actually be using DNSoverTLS to speak to the root servers. Thanks for your help clearing this up!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. =)